# AuthGuard while returning false and redirecting to pageNotFound creates 2 instances of the previous page

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular6

Im using canActivate and canActivateChild to guard my routes.If the user tries to navigate by using a path in the URL he doesn't have access to it works fine by returning false. But while it redirects the user to pageNotFound page it creates an 2 instances of the page i.e the URL from where the user tried to change the path. So when using the back button of browser we have click it twice instead of once.

Eg.

This are the main routes

```
export const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: "", // for default page{login}
  redirectTo: "login",
  pathMatch: "full"
},
{
  path: "default-layout",
  component: DefaultLayoutComponent,
  canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
  canActivateChild:[AuthGuardService],
  children: defaultRoutes
},

{
  path:'pageNotFound',
  component:PageNotFoundComponent,
},
];
```

The children path

```
const defaultRoutes: Routes = [
 { path: "dashboard", component: DashboardComponent },
 { path: "no-access", component: NoAccessComponent },
 { path: "refer-friend", component: ReferFriendComponent },
 { path: "chart", component: ChartUI },
 { path: "home", component: ChartUI },
 { path: "stock-scanners", component: StockScanners },  
]
```

The authService

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    return this.checkRoleAndGrantAccess(route, state)
}

canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    return this.checkRoleAndGrantAccess(route, state)
}

checkRoleAndGrantAccess(route, state) {
 let   roleList: any = []
 let   list: any = []
 let   value: any = false;
 let   obj:any

    obj= this.paramService.getParams('roleList');
    roleList=obj.roleList

    if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {

        if (roleList) {
            list = roleList.filter(item => item.routing == state.url);

            if (list.length > 0) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                this.router.navigate(['/pageNotFound']);
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;

    }
    // not logged in so redirect to login page
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
}
```

Consider my current url is default-layout/dashboard and i navigate to default-layout/chart. Now when i use the back button of browser it goes back in one click no problem.

But if i use a wrong after default-layout/chart the guard will navigate it to pageNotFound url. Now on clicking the browsers back button once it comes back to default-layout/chart. (Now on clicking back button one more time it should go back to  default-layout/dashboard ) but it doesn't and goes back to default-layout/chart. As 2 instances of default-layout/chart are generated in the browser. (one when we navigate to default-layout/chart and the other one when the authGuard returns false and navigates to pageNotFound)